# Script to get definitions of table types and Sequences

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, scripting, sequence, user-defined-table-type

I need to get the definition of some objects in the SQL server. I got the definitions of stored procedures, functions, views and triggers from sys.sql_modules.

But, I don't know how to get that of user-defined table types and of sequences. I am trying to create this in another database and automate this process.

Does anyone know how to get the definition of table types and sequences?

Comment: SMO will do this for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter?view=sql-smo-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still working on the create script, huh? ;-). Below the meta data of the objects requested.

```
/*The configuration of the sequences*/
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects AS o
    JOIN sys.sequences AS s
        ON s.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'SO';

/*The columns of the table types*/
SELECT tt.name,
       c.*
FROM sys.table_types tt
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON c.object_id = tt.type_table_object_id
ORDER BY c.column_id;
```

Comment: Hi Peter , This only give the names of the types and sequences , what I needed was the definition . Thanks anyway . You guys are great 

Comment: The create script, is as far as I know not defined in a definition, but you can create it based on the columns in the s.* (sequences) and the c.* (table types).

Comment: Yeah! I have don it for table types.now working on sequences . Thank you❤️